# Unable to access table data from php script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a script that is accessing a remote MySQL database. This database has multiple tables with more than 4 billion (yes, I mean billion) records.

Today I created a new table with around 6.3 million records. When I access the database and more specifically the new table via Sequel Pro, I'm able to do queries and get data from any table in the database without any issues, this includes accessing the new table I just created.

THE PROBLEM IS: When I access the same database using the same user credentials via PHP, I am unable to access the new table I just created. I am able to access data in every other table in the database but just not the new table I created.

Here's what I've tried:
I first tried making the connection and queries via PDO. When that didn't work I tried making the connection and queries with mysqli. Neither of these methods worked. In order to make sure I wasn't missing something in my script, I created the script below that gets a list of every table in the database and then accesses each table, grabs 2 records, and outputs them to the screen:

```
 try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=IP_ADDRESS;port=PORT_NUMBER;dbname=DB_NAME', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD', [
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
     ]);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
 }

 $query = $db->query('SHOW TABLES');
 $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

 foreach ($results as $r) {
    echo '<br><br>' . $r . '<br>';
    $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . $r . "` LIMIT 2");

    foreach ($res as $row) {
        echo '<br>';
        print_r($row);
    }
 }
```

This script is able to retrieve records from every table but the new table.

**More Information:**
 -This is a MySQL database on a Windows 10 machine that is hosted remotely.

 -The user has access full access to all tables in the DB.

 -I created the table with the default DB options: encoding: utf8, collation: utf8_general_ci, table type: InnoDB

 -The table was created from Sequel Pro using a INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
SELECT ..... statement.

 -I'm accessing the DB with a Macbook Pro using MAMP Pro and I haven't really changed any of the default PHP settings.

Comment: You're not checking for errors. Exceptions are not enabled in PDO, therefore it'll just return boolean false on failure, and you're not checking for that false return value. That means you're just ASSUMING everything will work perfectly and never fail. Never EVER assume success. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you for the suggestion on the error checking, but as I stated before I tried this with both PDO and mysqli and got the same result. I'm able to access every table in my db but the one I just created. And I didn't post it but the mysqli code I used included this error check:   `if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}`

Comment: checking for connection errors is utterly useless in this case. you did connect. you're just ASSUMINg the query() calls never fail. it's like driving into the back of your garage wall, and saying "everything's fine, I didn't hit anything on the freeway". you need to check EVERY db query call for failure, not just the connection.

Comment: @MarcB When I use `$db->errorInfo()` right after my PDO query. I get the following: `Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )`

Comment: which query? the show tables? that was obviously working, since you got other tables. what about the `select` query?

Comment: @MarcB No, I called it right after a new query that I created that only called the table that I am having issues with. So the script just opened the connection, tried to SELECT 2 entries from the problem table, and then called the errorInfo statement. I got no errors. I've also been monitoring the php error log this whole time and no errors have been displayed there either.

Comment: What is the name of the problem table? Is the table listed in the output of `SHOW TABLES` but the `SELECT` returns nothing or is it not listed at all?

Comment: @MattRaines Yes, the problem table gets listed in the SHOW TABLES statement and then the SELECT returns nothing. The name of the table is `cdbaby`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'd be surprised if this helps anyone else. BUT the thing that fixed my problem was adding another field to the table. I did this via Sequel Pro's "Structure" interface. Since my table had 6.4 million records it took a little while to add the field, but once it completed I was able to access the table via PHP without any issues.